# class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource in Android 10 only

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to load image in Android 10.But its not working in android 10.Below the android 10 its working fine.Is there any solution let me know.I am working on this error last 4 days.In emulator its working fine.In Redmi note 6 pro phones android 10 showing this error

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
2020-03-30 21:24:47.797 28113-28113/com.example.mfree W/Glide: Load failed for https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mfree-9290a.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F1585237282229.null?alt=media&token=fbf576df-2c63-44bf-886d-58b32d5f49e5 with size [120x120]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(SSL handshake timed out)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(SSL handshake timed out)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException(SSL handshake timed out)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
2020-03-30 21:24:47.801 28113-28113/com.example.mfree I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
            java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to firebasestorage.googleapis.com/172.217.160.138 (port 443) from /192.168.43.76 (port 45592) after 2500ms
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
                at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:141)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:104)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:59)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:150)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:144)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:65)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:99)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

Glide

```
 Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage()).into(holder.post_image);
```

Comment: Do you have working internet connection?

Comment: Yes.  Its working in on the below of Android 10

Comment: Then please add this line into your manifest application tag `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: not working sir

Comment: You can debug this issue by.
- load other image url with glide. if it loads then problem must be with your URL and if it doesn't then try updating Glide library version. Hope it helps.

Comment: its may be - this problem     java.net.SocketTimeoutException(SSL handshake timed out)

Comment: did you find this solution ? i m facing same issue

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and fixed it by adding a timeout.

In your case it would look like this:

```
 Glide.with(mContext)
      .load(post.getPostimage())
      .timeout(6000) // 60 second timeout
      .into(holder.post_image);
```